# How to use an external non vue script in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I try to use an external script (https://libs.crefopay.de/3.0/secure-fields.js) which is not vue based

I added the script via -tags into index.html

But when I try to intsanciate an object, like in the excample of the script publisher.

```
let secureFieldsClientInstance =
      new SecureFieldsClient('xxxxx',
        this.custNo,
        this.paymentRegisteredCallback,
        this.initializationCompleteCallback,
        configuration)
```

Vue says "'SecureFieldsClient' is not defined"

If I use *this.*

```
let secureFieldsClientInstance =
          new this.SecureFieldsClient('xxxxx',
            this.custNo,
            this.paymentRegisteredCallback,
            this.initializationCompleteCallback,
            configuration)
        secureFieldsClientInstance.registerPayment()
```

Vue says: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.SecureFieldsClient is not a constructor"

My Code:

```
methods: {
startPayment () {
  this.state = null
  if (!this.selected) {
    this.state = false
    this.msg = 'Bitte Zahlungsweise auswählen.'
  } else {
    localStorage.payment = this.selected
    let configuration = {
      url: 'https://sandbox.crefopay.de/secureFields/',
      placeholders: {
      }
    }
    let secureFieldsClientInstance =
      new SecureFieldsClient('xxxxx',
        this.custNo,
        this.paymentRegisteredCallback,
        this.initializationCompleteCallback,
        configuration)
    secureFieldsClientInstance.registerPayment()
    // this.$router.replace({ name: 'payment' })
  }
}
}
```

Where is my mistake?

EDIT:
Updated the hole question

Comment: Have you tried to add it to index.html file?

Comment: how? the start file is App.vue. the index.html is generated.

Comment: ah found the index.html but still get "TypeError: this.SecureFieldsClient is not a constructor"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

the import was never the problem.

I had just to ignore VUEs/eslints complaining about the missing "this" via // eslint-disable-next-line and it works.

So external fuctions/opbjects should be called without "this" it seems.

```
let secureFieldsClientInstance =
      new SecureFieldsClient('xxxxx',
        this.custNo,
        this.paymentRegisteredCallback,
        this.initializationCompleteCallback,
        configuration)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a minimal Vue app for the context your provided, which works:
https://codepen.io/krukid/pen/voxqPj

Without additional details it's hard to say what your specific problem is, but most probably the library gets loaded **after** your method executes, so `window.SecureFieldsClient` is expectedly not yet defined. Or, there is some runtime error that crashes your script and prevents your method from executing. There could be some other more exotic issues, but lacking a broader context I can only speculate.

To ensure your library loads before running any code from it, you should attach an `onload` listener to your external script:

```
mounted () {
  let crefPayApi = document.createElement('script')
  crefPayApi.onload = () => this.startPayment()
  crefPayApi.setAttribute('src', 'https://libs.crefopay.de/3.0/secure-fields.js')
  document.head.appendChild(crefPayApi)
},
```

Comment: A quick note on this: keep in mind that scripts that were dynamically added like this have certain security mechanisms in place to prevent malicious intent. You would for example not be able to use `document.write` from within that script.

Comment: @buffy Though it is true external scripts are subject to a whole bunch of browser checks - whether it's CSP or CORB, `document.write` would not work as expected in a dynamically inserted script because the document will have been closed by the time the script runs. It may work if you include the script synchronously.

Comment: thanks for your answer but its not a typo. getCustomerData is a function to initialy load data into the page. this.startPayment is triggered by a buttonclick

Comment: @Eardy cool, future pointer is to include all the relevant code and/or exclude irrelevant parts (minimize the use case), otherwise it gets confusing, there are lots of typos on SO. Anyway, see the updated answer.

Comment: it's not working either. still get " this.SecureFieldsClient is not a constructor" I don't think it's a timing problem, the page is fully loaded, when I click the button. what more context do you need? it's a quite simple page.

Comment: i added the script via script tag into the index.html but still get the message "TypeError: this.SecureFieldsClient is not a constructor"

Answer (score -1):

You could download the script and then use the `import` directive to load the script via webpack. You probably have something like `import Vue from 'vue';` in your project. This just imports vue from your node modules.

It's the exact same thing for other external scripts, just use a relative path. When using Vue-CLI, you can do `import i18n from './i18n';`, where the `src` folder would contain a `i18n.js`

If you really want to use a CDN, you can add it like you normally would and then add it to the externals: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals to make it accessible from within webpack

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I would rather not download this file, because it's quite securety relevant and I wan't it always be up to date.